# What's the condition(s) for a generator to be mapped to a generator by a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A simple fact is that if $\phi : G \rightarrow H$ is an isomorphism where $G$ and $H$ are cyclic groups (of the same order, of course),  then a generator is mapped to a generator. It's equivalent to saying that $|x|=|\phi (x)|$, or that both $|x|\ge|\phi (x)|$ and $|x|\le|\phi (x)|$. We only verify the latter one below.

Note that 
$x^{|\phi (x)|}=\phi^{-1}(\phi (x))^{|\phi (x)|}=\phi^{-1}(\phi(x)^{|\phi (x)|})=\phi^{-1}(\phi(1))=1$, the identity of $G$ .We can write an inverse function $\phi^{-1} : H \rightarrow G$ without ambiguity while it also being an homomorphism since $\phi$ is an isomorphism. It maps every $\phi(x)$ back to $x$

but for $\phi^{-1}$ to be well-defined, it seems that $\phi$ only needs to be injective. And it seems that such homomorphism must also be surjective(?). Just consider the trivial homomorphism, which maps every element of $G$ to the identity of $H$. Are there some example(s) that $\phi$ is injective, not surjective, but still maps generators to generators? What if $G$ and $H$ are cyclic groups of different orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a generator is mapped to a generator, then the map is necessarily surjective.

To be more precise: Suppose that $x$ generates $G$ and $\phi(x)$ generates $H$, where $\phi: G \to H$ is some homomorphism. Let $y$ be any element of $H$. Since $\phi(x)$ generates $H$, there is some $m$ such that $\phi(x)^m = y$. Since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, this becomes $\phi(x^m) = y$, and thus $y$ is in the image of $\phi$. Since $y \in H$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $\phi$ is surjective.

If, in addition, we assume that $\phi$ is injective, then we conclude that $\phi$ is an isomorphism and $G$ and $H$ are cyclic of the same order.

Comment: What about a surjective, but not injective map? Say $|G|$ is greater than $|H|$.

Comment: Yes, that can happen: Just map $G$ to the trivial group.